# Aronszajn tree with antichain on club many levels

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am wondering if a normal $\omega_1$-Aronszajn tree that has a big antichain (of size $\omega_1$) $A$ with the set $$ \mathrm{rk} (A) := \{ \theta: \exists x \in A ( \mathrm{ht} (x) = \theta )\}$$
club in $\omega_1$ is consistent with ZFC.

To my knowledge it is consistent that $\mathrm{rk} (A)$ be stationary. I was trying to produce a branch under the assumptions but got stuck. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged as forcing?

Comment: I wonder how to prove the $\operatorname{rk}(A)$ can be a stationary subset of $\omega_1$. Would you mind to give a reference for it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila . Is it consistent that rk(A) is never stationary?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I'm afraid that trees are not my particular speciality. So I have no idea. I do think that if you have an Aronszajn tree with an antichain with stationary levels, you can shoot a club into that stationary set and *probably* preserve the tree as Aronszajn. Although I'm not entirely sure, and way too lazy to think about the details right now.

Comment: Ah, maybe I need to edit my question. I saw in an abstract in a paper where it's proved that a tree can have all antichains on non-stationary level sets. It's done by an iteration ensuring so (i'd imagine). As in shooting a club through the complement of the $\textrm{rk}$ of the potential antichains, etc.

Comment: Under $MA_{\omega_1}$, every Aronszajn tree $T$ has an antichain whose nodes occur at every infinite level. The proof is standard: Force with finite order preserving maps from $T$ to the set of rationals.